# datepicker + webdriver + unable to identify the element

Tags: selenium, webdriver

In my application i have a text box which when i click brings the date picker to select a date. One way is to select the date from datepicker or u can manually send in the date. But whenever i send in the date it says it is unable to locate the element.

THis is code for sending the date to the text box

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtdateFrom']")).sendKeys("03/05/2013");
```

It throws the following error

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='txtdateFrom']"}
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:52:59'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_17'
Session ID: 3eea4ac2-2b38-4688-9733-8734077f7d3e
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

I dont have the privilege to add the screenshot.
Please help!!

Please find the HTML below

```
<input id="txtdateFrom" class="textbox hasDatepicker" type="text" style="color:Gray;" name="txtdateFrom">
```

Please find the iframe HTMl

```
<iframe width="100%" scrolling="auto" height="493" frameborder="1" style="vertical-align: top;" allowtransparency="true" id="ContentMain" src="../Report/AuditorAssignmentReportSearch.aspx?Width=100&amp;Height=528"></iframe>
```

DOM of the text field which when clicked will populate datepicker

```
  attributes
    [type="text", style="color:Gray;", 2 more...]

0
    type="text"

1
    style="color:Gray;"

2
    class="textbox hasDatepicker"

3
    id="txtdateFrom"

4
    name="txtdateFrom"
```

and this is the attribute of the datepicker once the text field is clicked

```
attributes
    [class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"]

0
    class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"
```

Updated DOM

```
attributes
    [onclick="DP_jQuery_1368459704950.datepicker._selectDay('#txtdateFrom',4,2013, this);return false;", class=

"  ui-datepicker-today"

]

0
    onclick="DP_jQuery_1368459704950.datepicker._selectDay('#txtdateFrom',4,2013, this);return false;"
```

Comment: Screenshots wouldn't help anyway, what you should always post for a Selenium/WebDrvier problem is the actual HTML.

Comment: @Ross Patterson : I have added the HTML code

Comment: @Sriram : why don't you use driver.findElement(By.id("txtdateFrom")).sendKeys("03/05/2013"); This may work for you if the date picker is not in iframe.

Comment: @Omkar : that has been tired as well.... I even tried it with CSS locator too (#txtdateFrom) but in vain :(

Comment: @Omkar : Few Questions. how do i find whether my datepicker is in iframe and if at all if it is in iframe what should i do the perform the action

Comment: WebElement whole_page = driver.findelement(By.id("id of whole page")); this will get all web element in whole page object.after that use List<WebElement> iframe = driver.findelements(By.tagname("iframe")); then check the size of System.out.println(iframe.size);

Comment: List<WebElement> iframe = driver.findelements(By.tagname("iframe")). It throws an error saying its unable to locate iframe... not sure if i made a mistake or something... I just used uur code.. kindly help

Comment: @Sriram :this means there is no iframe in u r webpage.

Comment: @Omkar : After prolonged search i found iframe in my webpage under which this date field is present. I tried to switch it to that frame using driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findelement(By.xpatH(....))).. But in vain.. It still throws the error.. Can u please help

Comment: @Sriram It will be possible for u to share URL of u r application

Comment: @Omkar : I guess its not possible.. Sorry :(

Comment: @Omkar : Now i am able to move into the frame but yet not able to find the element.

Comment: @Sriram : How U are switching into iframe ? can u paste the command here as well.

Comment: @Omkar : Sorry in the above code i pasted iframe id is missing... Iframe id is "ContentMain". so my code is driver.switchTo().frame("ContentMain"); or driver.switchTo().frame(0);

Comment: @Sriram :Does it Showing element not found error for Date Picker after Switching into an iframe?

Comment: @Omkar : yes. Once after i move into the i frame. i tried to click the text box to invoke the calendar or tried to send the date directly.. Both cases it says its unable to locate the element (textbox)

Comment: @Sriram :As you are doing it should work.It crosses my limit too :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up thanks for the support and all the suggestions. The issue was with browser compatibility. Our Application works only in IE 8. The whole time i was using IE 9. When i checked my code in IE 8 it works perfectly and am able to enter the date. Thanks All!!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should use js executor:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.document.getElementById('txtdateFrom').setAttribute('value', '03/05/2013');");
```

Attribute may be different, you should search for it in DOM.

Or may be selenium doesn't wait for element and can't find it. Can you find this element without sending keys to it?

Comment: When i try ur code it throws the following error org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: TypeError: window.document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: THe webdriver is able to find the element when i send this code of urs. js.executeScript("window.document.getElementById('txtdateFrom') but throws the error i previously mentioned if i give the entire code js.executeScript("window.document.getElementById('txtdateFrom').setAttribute('value', '03/05/2013');");

Comment: What about this? js.executeScript("window.document.getElementById('txtdateFrom').value='03/05/2013'

Comment: It needs to see DOM to understand where is a problem, may be you can share link to the page?

Comment: am sorry its not possible for me to share the link.. and btw js.executeScript("window.document.getElementById('txtdateFrom').value='03/05/201‌​3' . is this correct?? i mean there are missing braces and quotes . Can u pls help so that i will try the above and let u know

Comment: The following is correct js.executeScript("window.document.getElementById('txtdateFrom').value='03/05/201‌​3';");

Comment: If this won't work, share the DOM of the datepicker. Or find which attribute reflects picked date(If it was picked manually).

Comment: It still throws the same error :(. Probabaly i will update the attribute fields present in the DOM in the above code.

Comment: I have updated the attributes with respect to text field and date picker

Comment: Pick any date manually and find this date in the DOM of the element.

Comment: Once i manually select the date, i am unable to find the date in the DOM :(

Comment: May be you are searching in wrong element? Selected date should be somewhere :)

Comment: bingo but i selected 22nd may 2013 but i was able to find the year 2013.. I have posted the DOM above in teh code

Comment: You should find the value which is currently displayed in textbox. I belief it exists)

Comment: i believe the same. But when i find with date or month am not able to find it.. but with year its present... Thats the DOM i have posted. Am not able to find it :( :(

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approach would be to try driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtdateFrom']")).click().sendKeys("03/05/2013");
Although sendKeys does that implicitly, sometimes a click into the Inputfield before sendKeys() is very useful, that's my experience. Further this xpath is ok but seems to be a copy&paste from firepath. I'd suggest you use //input[@id='txtdateFrom']. So it's more readable.

Comment: Even after changing the xpath as u suggested it throws the same error

Comment: did you also try to perform a click into the input before filling in your desired date?